# how to add Space between 2 rows using panelGrid in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, dynamic-visualforce, dynamic-vf-component

I am using panelGrid for this UI.
Please fetch the code and Ui below and lt me know where I can add the css in order to increase the spaces between the rows.
I have used rowclasses attribute in the panelGrid but it had no effect.

```
<apex:page standardController="Voucher__c"  recordSetVar="comp" extensions="CreateComp_Controller" docType="html-5.0" lightningstylesheets="true"> 
<style>
  .pannelConfigs {
    margin-left: 150px;
  }
    .rowConfigs {
   padding: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
  }
</style>
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="Create Component"  mode="edit">
  <apex:pageBlockSection id="E-voucher" title="E-Voucher"   >
    <apex:panelGrid columns="2" rowClasses="rowConfigs" styleClass="pannelConfigs" width="200%"  >
    <apex:panelGroup >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Voucher 1"  />
 <apex:inputField value="{!comp.Voucher_1__c}"  /> <br/>
    </apex:panelGroup>
    <apex:panelGroup >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Voucher Amount 1" />
<apex:inputField value="{!comp.Voucher_Amount_1__c}"  />
        </apex:panelGroup>    
         <apex:panelGroup >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Voucher 2"  />
 <apex:inputField value="{!comp.Voucher_2__c}"  /> <br/>
    </apex:panelGroup>
    <apex:panelGroup >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Voucher Amount 2" />
<apex:inputField value="{!comp.Voucher_Amount_2__c}"  />
        </apex:panelGroup>
         <apex:panelGroup >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Voucher 3" />
 <apex:inputField value="{!comp.Voucher_3__c}"  /> <br/>
    </apex:panelGroup>
    <apex:panelGroup >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Voucher Amount 3" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!comp.Voucher_Amount_3__c}"  />
        </apex:panelGroup>  
        </apex:panelGrid>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
 </apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image: UI image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

First, your CSS is wrong:

```
  <style>
    .pannelConfigs {
      margin-left: 150px;
    }
      .rowConfigs {
     padding: 300px;
      padding-bottom: 300px;
      margin-bottom: 300px: // This should be a semi-colon!
    }
  </style>
```

CSS properties are always in the form of `prop: value;`, where the last character is a semi-colon, not a colon. The latter may cause the property to be ignored.

Second, you didn't actually specify the row classes:

```
<apex:panelGrid rowClasses="rowConfigs" columns="2" ...>
```

Third, you need to select the rows directly in your CSS, otherwise the normal table rules will override your styles.

Here's a functional example:

```
<style>
    .rows td {
        height: 100px;
    }
</style>
<apex:panelGrid rowClasses="rows" columns="2">
    <apex:outputPanel>
        Value 1
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel>
        Value 2
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel>
        Value 3
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel>
        Value 4
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel>
        Value 5
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:panelGrid>
```

In addition, I should note that you might not want to use an apex:panelGrid here; apex:pageBlockSection should be sufficient.

I would advise not using `apex:panelGrid`. Instead, you could render the fields correctly and add `apex:pageBlockSectionItem` as blank spaces:

```
<style>
    table > tbody > tr > td.rows {
    padding: 300px !important;
    padding-bottom: 300px !important;
    margin-bottom: 300px !important;
    }
</style>
<apex:pageBlock title="Create Component"  mode="edit">
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="E-voucher" title="E-Voucher">
        <apex:inputField value="{!comp.Voucher_1__c}"  />
        <apex:inputField value="{!comp.Voucher_Amount_1__c}" />
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="rows"><span style="display:none"></span></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="rows"><span style="display:none"></span></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:inputField value="{!comp.Voucher_2__c}"  />
        <apex:inputField value="{!comp.Voucher_Amount_2__c}"  />
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="rows"><span style="display:none"></span></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="rows"><span style="display:none"></span></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:inputField value="{!comp.Voucher_3__c}"  />
        <apex:inputField value="{!comp.Voucher_Amount_3__c}"  />
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

If you don't really need the 300px padding, which sounds excessive, given you just added a `<br />`, which could look like:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Create Component"  mode="edit">
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="E-voucher" title="E-Voucher">
        <apex:inputField value="{!comp.Voucher_1__c}"  />
        <apex:inputField value="{!comp.Voucher_Amount_1__c}" />
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
        <apex:inputField value="{!comp.Voucher_2__c}"  />
        <apex:inputField value="{!comp.Voucher_Amount_2__c}"  />
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
        <apex:inputField value="{!comp.Voucher_3__c}"  />
        <apex:inputField value="{!comp.Voucher_Amount_3__c}"  />
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback .Made the changes but still didnt work.

Comment: How ever I used extra <br/> tags and it worked.
Please let me know if there is any better way to do it.

Comment: @Reettik It needs some additional selectivity, it appears. I wrote a functional example for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help @sfdcfox.I was able to understand it clearly and also implemented it.
I was having another issue ie is the UI order is disoriented.
Can you suggest me a fix to maintain a good ui where the label length would not affect the input fields location. Please fetch the new screen sort attached.
I was using a custom style class and providing a margin left  but it was constant for all.Can you suggest me any formula to calculate and provide a specific space between them.

Comment: @Reettik Stop using the apex:panelGrid.

Comment: I have stopped using panel grid instead I am using page block section item.